# Redirect failed when setting a custom handler

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2.4

I have the following code in my custom config file.

```
<Directory "/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    ErrorDocument 403 "Please disable proxies to view content."
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
    RewriteRule ^faq/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ faq.php?code=$1&num=$2 [NC]
</Directory>
```

Now, when I browse to a webpage like `/index.phps` or `/some/other/dir/and/file.phps`, I get a 404 error in the browser and the following is logged in the error log for apache:

```
[<date>] [:error] [pid 15154:tid 3024079728] [client <IP>] script 'redirect:/request/get_req.php' not found or unable to stat
[<date>] [:error] [pid 15152:tid 2914974576] [client <IP>] script 'redirect:/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

*What could be causing this issue?* Also, please note that the second `RewriteRule` for `faq/..` is working perfectly. I have a few more rewrite rules in per directory basis `htaccess` files and all of them are working as well.

The server version I'm using is *Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)*.

---

After following advice from [covener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081526/1190388) and [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24091529/1190388); I updated my `conf` file to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www"
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)s$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
    # RewriteRule ^/?(.*\.php)s$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)s$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
    RewriteRule ^faq/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ faq.php?code=$1&num=$2 [NC]
</Directory>
```

But the handler for php source is still logging the same error:

```
[<date>] [:error] [pid 17586:tid 2956938096] [client <IP>] script 'redirect:/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you need to take out this code snippet out of `<Directory>` container and place it in `<VirtualHost>` block:

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
```

Reason why it works in `<VirtualHost>` block is because rewrite happens in an early phase of
apache processing i.e `per-server` context. However when it happens in `per-dir` context, it happens in a late phase and causes the request to be restarted after the substitution. If a substitution is made in per-directory context, a new internal subrequest is issued with the new URL, which restarts processing of the request phases.

See this [mod_rewrite tech reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html) for more details

**My `VirtualHost` entry:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    ErrorDocument 403 "Please disable proxies to view content."
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source,NC]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have placed code **exactly shown above** in `VirtualHost` section and it works great for `http://localhost/index.phps` request showing highlighted text. I have placed my `VirtualHost` entry above.

Comment: +1 because you're certainly the best at explaining things in a very detailled way for beginners, but I gave the bounty to @covener, he made the hardest part of the task, finding the technical limitations. Hope you understand.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to give him bounty and it is your prerogative.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a per-directory substitution and set the Handler (H=), because the mechanics of how mod_rewrite does per-directory substitutions requires the handler to be set to mod_rewrite itself.

A per-dir substitution does two things:

- Sets the handler to a special mod_rewrite handler
- prefixes the mapped filename with redirect:

So by setting H=, you're blowing away 1 and seeing in your error message the core of apache trying to cope with "redirect:/..." as a filename.

It's an documented limitation of per-directory rewrite and this H= flag does not work, but not that it breaks the rewrite:

> Flags that alter metadata associated with the request (T=, H=, E=)
>   have no affect in per-directory and htaccess context, when a
>   substitution (other than '-') is performed during the same round of
>   rewrite processing.

You should pull your rewrite directives out of <Directory> context and restore the leading prefix (/ ?) to your first parameter and make sure your 2nd parameter substitutions are absolute URL-paths and not relative URL-paths.  Outside of directory context, there is no internal redirect required and everything is much simpler.

e.g. to make it safe for non per-dir context:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)s$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
RewriteRule ^/faq/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ /faq.php?code=$1&num=$2 [NC]
```

In this context, your URL gets mapped to a file and the handler is set, there is no re-introducing the URL back into the Apache processing because it is a simple uri->file mapping.
I

Comment: Interesting. If you add more details on the Header/Handler mistake and an example of ou-of-directory rewrite I'll give you the bounty right now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant. The second rule has not been giving me any issues. The leading `/?` match works because there is no directory named `faq`. What happens is that the first rule (to redirect all `.phps` requests to respective `.php` file with custom header) is trying to redirect correctly but returning a 404 error instead.

Comment: @regilero, I elaborated a bit in the answer. 
hjpotter92 --  the issue is that the custom handler (not header) is not preserved across the rewrite, it's not usable in per-directory context. This is actually documented.

Comment: I updated the conf file and restarted the server. The issue is still there.